# Change submit button text of Google Form using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

How can I change the submit button text of a Google Form, which is fixed to "submit", into another text like "Participate now" using Google Script. I should add some code like

```
var form = FormApp.openById(formUrl);
setTextSubmitButton("Participate");
```

but I'm completely new to Google Script so I have no idea on how to do this. Could not figure out from the Google Script Reference docs either on how to access and modify this text.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

You cannot do this in Google Forms.

#### More information:

There's no way to customize the `Submit` button text in Google Forms, let alone programmatically via Apps Script.

Since this is not available to the core product (Forms) either, I'd suggest you to request this feature via `Send feedback` at https://docs.google.com/forms.

Comment: What I find strange is that there exists an AddOn that says it can change the submit button text but that it is not possible to do it programmatically (see https://formfacade.com/website/change-google-forms-submit-button-text.html#:~:text=settings-,You%20cannot%20change%20the%20button%20text%20directly%20in%20Google%20Forms,%2C%20style%2C%20language%20%26%20more.)

Comment: @julesd They're not changing the "submit" button, but they're recreating the entire Google form in their domain formfacade.com. It's no more a Google form, but plain html/css in their own website.